# Get size of Site directory in Orchard

Tags: directory, storage, orchardcms, media, orchardcms-1.6

crosspost: https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/456226

In Orchard, each site (whether or not you enable multitenancy) seems to have it's own Folder within Media (main file folder for Orchard). I want to get the entire filesize of a current site (ergo, the folder under Media).

I've digged into the Framework and got into `FileSystemStorageProvider` which seems to be promising with the `FileSystemStorageFolder` class and `GetSize()` method.

However, I was wondering if anyone else checked this out before I go into experimenting with that class.

Any piece of information or advise would be highly apreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't really find an easy way to do it but copied mostly from the Orchard framework. You will need the following:

```
private FileSystemStorageProvider _filesystemProvider;
private ShellSettings _settings;
```

And then you need to define the Site Storage Path:

```
var mediaPath = HostingEnvironment.IsHosted
                                ? HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Media/") ?? ""
                                : Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Media");  
storagePath = Path.Combine(mediaPath, _settings.Name);
```

Finally, here is my function to compute the storage for a specific folder (in this case, the tenant's/site's root media folder):

```
public double GetSiteStorage()
        {
            var folders = _filesystemProvider.ListFolders(storagePath);
            long totalSize = 0;

            foreach (var folder in folders)
            {
                totalSize += folder.GetSize();
            }

            return (totalSize / 1024 / 1024);
        }
```

This returns a double for the MB used. Hope this helps someone :)